# Merging pandas column from dataframe to another dataframe based on their indices

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame, `df_one` that looks like this where `video_id` is the index:

```
+----------+--------------+---------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+------------------+
|          | video_length | feed_position | time_watched | unique_watched | count_watched | avg_time_watched |
+----------+--------------+---------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+------------------+
| video_id |              |               |              |                |               |                  |
| 5        |           17 | 12.000000     |           17 |              1 |             1 | 1.000000         |
| 10       |           22 | 10.000000     |            1 |              1 |             1 | 0.045455         |
| 15       |           22 | 13.000000     |           22 |              1 |             1 | 1.000000         |
| 22       |           29 | 20.000000     |            5 |              1 |             1 | 0.172414         |
+----------+--------------+---------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+------------------+
```

And I have another dataframe, `df_two` that looks like this where `video_id` is also the index:

```
+----------+--------------+---------------+--------------+----------------+------------------------+
|          | video_length | feed_position | time_watched | unique_watched | count_watched_yeterday |
+----------+--------------+---------------+--------------+----------------+------------------------+
| video_id |              |               |              |                |                        |
| 5        |          102 | 11.333333     |           73 |              6 |                      6 |
| 15       |           22 | 13.000000     |           22 |              1 |                      1 |
| 16       |           44 | 2.000000      |           15 |              1 |                      1 |
| 17       |          180 | 23.333333     |           53 |              6 |                      6 |
| 18       |           40 | 1.000000      |           40 |              1 |                      1 |
+----------+--------------+---------------+--------------+----------------+------------------------+
```

What I want to do is merge the `count_watched_yeterday` column from `df_two` to `df_one` based on the index of each.

I tried:

```
video_base = pd.merge(df_one, df_two['count_watched_yeterday'], how='left', on=[df_one.index, df_two.index])
```

But I got this error:
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: try `video_base = pd.merge(df_one, df_two[['count_watched_yeterday']], how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)`

Comment: @EdChum This worked! Could you explain why it worked and why I would need the left_index and right_index arguments?

Comment: Firstly I think you need to pass dfs not a series, `df_two['count_watched_yeterday']` is a Series not a df, by using double square brackets your force a df of a single column, secondly you're supposed to pass a list of columns for the `on` parameter, not the indices, so this won't work, if you want to merge on index you have to set the params `left_index=True` and `right_index=True`

Comment: The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html#pandas.merge) show what the default params are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I think the easiest thing to do here is to directly assign:

```
In [13]:    
df['count_watched_yesterday'] = df1['count_watched_yeterday']
df['count_watched_yesterday']

Out[13]:
video_id
5      6
10   NaN
15     1
22   NaN
Name: count_watched_yesterday, dtype: float64
```

This works because it will align on the index values, where you have no matching values a `NaN` will be assigned as the value